# Word VBA Convert Highlight to Shade (1) How to limit Code to Selected Range? (2) Is there Code more efficient than Char by Character+ loop each color?

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight, maven-shade-plugin

Title says it all: `Can convert Highlight to Shading` learnt from [Convert Texts from Highlighted to Shaded via VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/convert-texts-shaded-highlighted-vice-versa-word-document/)

Want to apply to `Selection` rather than whole document.
Also takes a long time to execute character by character for each of 16 base colour Highlights.

Coders probably know a far more efficient routine.

```vb
    Sub ConvertHighlightToShade()
      Dim objCharacterRange As Range
      For Each objCharacterRange In ActiveDocument.Characters
            If objCharacterRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdDarkBlue Then
          objCharacterRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
          objCharacterRange.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 0, 128) 'DarkBlue
               Debug.Print "1of16", "Conv Hlgt t Shad.1of16", "#000080", "DarkBlue"
        End If
      Next objCharacterRange
      For Each objCharacterRange In ActiveDocument.Characters
            If objCharacterRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen Then
          objCharacterRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
          objCharacterRange.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(0, 128, 0) 'Green
               Debug.Print "4of16", "Conv Hlgt t Shad.4of16", "#008000", "Green"
        End If
      Next objCharacterRange
      End Sub
```

I tried use the following model to isolate the Selection area, but variations failed.

https://www.bettersolutions.com/word/characters/vba-range-object.htm

Redefining a Range Object

You can use the `SetRange` method to redefine an existing Range object
The following example defines a range object to the be equal to the current selection and then redefines it to refer to the current selection plus the next 10 characters.

```
    Dim objRange As Range 
    Set objRange = ActiveWindow.Selection.Range 
    objRange.SetRange(Start:=objRange.Start, _ 
                  End:=objRange.End+10)
```

I note the advantages of using a Range appear in
https://bettersolutions.com/word/characters/vba-range-vs-selection.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to crawl through the document character by character. Word's built-in Find function will find the highlighted text for you.

The routine below replaces the highlight with shading of the same color.

```
Sub ConvertHighlightToShade()
    Dim findRange As Range: Set findRange = Selection.Range
    With findRange
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Highlight = True
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If findRange.InRange(Selection.Range) Then
                .Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = .HighlightColorIndex
                .HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
                .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy, brilliant programming, the conversion commences correctly at the beginning of the Selection, but goes beyond the Selection to the end of the document.
Can it be adjusted to contain its operation to where the Selection ends?
If not, it is still a really commendable fix.
Btw Apologies for delayed follow-up.

Comment: @CDuv - please see edited code in answer.

Comment: Timothy, amazing upgrade it confines the conversion to within the selected range. 
Important Parameters: 
1. It will not work on sections over Highlight overlap, must separate overlap sections before converting.
Cure: separate overlap sections before converting
2. Converting part way through Highlight section at beginning works precisely: good
3. Converting part way through Highlight section at end will not work. None of the last Highlighted on sections will be converted 
Cure: make sure the Selected Range always includes at least one character of clear at the end.
Gold Status Deserving

Comment: Just realised I am not eligible to put a rating on this VBA answer.
Can some one eligible check it out, and rate on our behalf?